# How to specify minimum word length in PostgreSQL full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is there a way to prevent words shorter than a specified value end up in `tsvector`? MySQL has the `ft_min_word_len` option, is there something similar for PostgreSQL?

Comment: it would be good to provide us with some use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer would be no.

The tsearch2 uses dictionaries to normalize the text:

> [12.6. Dictionaries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html)
>
> Dictionaries are used to eliminate words that should not be considered
>   in a search (stop words), and to normalize words so that different
>   derived forms of the same word will match. A successfully normalized
>   word is called a lexeme.

and how the dictionaries are used [Parsing and Lexing](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/docs/tsearch2-guide.html#parsing_lexing)

Comment: Then I will preprocess text and substitute letters of short words with X. Then I could define X, XX, XXX... as stop words. Positions would be preserverd and short words would not be indexed.